# docker-compose throws error when not run with sudo

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have `docker` installed and fully functional.
`docker run hello-world` works just fine and I can build and run any other image.

Then I installed `docker-compose` using [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

I'm on **Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)**.

This is the list of the commands that I have run:

```
 sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

 sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

 sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

And I can verify the installation:

```
$ docker-compose --version
```

> docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

But when I run `docker-compose up` I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 153, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
[18196] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

However, when I use `sudo docker-compose up` everything works just fine.

I also tried a couple of permission solutions:

```
    sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

    sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
    sudo chgrp docker /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

But none of them changes anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to be in the `docker` group or use `sudo`. And make sure to log out and in after adding yourself to the group.

Comment: My bad. I just closed terminal and reopened it. After restart it worked. Thank you for the note @KlausD.